# MySQL QUERY with 4 tables; is there a way to make it faster and use less resources?

Tags: mysql, optimization

just a question about MySQL, to speed up the query.

I have 4 tables:

```
- PROD_sell (744 rows):
PROD_SELL_id | USER_id | PROD_sell_crediti | PROD_SELL_datepay |
 - PROD_newsletter (7300 rows)
USER_id | NEWSL_ref_area | NEWSL_ref_subprod | USER_realcf_area | USER_realcf_page_num | 
  - PROD_archivio (197 rows)
PROD_ARCH_id | PROD_ARCH_hidden | PROD_CAT_id |
 - PROD_cat (3 rows)
PROD_CAT_id | PROD_CAT_title |
```

This is my query (via php):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT s.PROD_SELL_id) AS count,
c.PROD_CAT_title
FROM PROD_sell AS s, PROD_newsletter AS n, PROD_archivio AS a, PROD_cat AS c
WHERE
s.USER_id = n.USER_id
AND 
((n.NEWSL_ref_area = 2 AND n.NEWSL_ref_subprod = a.PROD_ARCH_id) 
OR 
(n.USER_realcf_area = 'archivio' AND n.USER_realcf_page_num = a.PROD_ARCH_id))
AND a.PROD_ARCH_hidden = '0'
AND a.PROD_CAT_id = c.PROD_CAT_id
AND s.PROD_sell_crediti = '0' AND s.PROD_SELL_datepay >= '$data_inizio_where' AND s.PROD_SELL_datepay <= '$data_fine_where'
GROUP BY a.PROD_CAT_id ASC
ORDER BY count DESC
```

The result is (for example):

```
CAT 1: 30 sales
CAT 2: 23 sales
CAT 3: 31 sales
and so on...
```

I know it looks orrible, it works but I need a faster way to make the same query, beacuse it takes a lot of resources and the site goes down.

The worst part, as you can guess, is:

```
AND 
((n.NEWSL_ref_area = 2 AND n.NEWSL_ref_subprod = a.PROD_ARCH_id) 
OR 
(n.USER_realcf_area = 'archivio' AND n.USER_realcf_page_num = a.PROD_ARCH_id))
```

Is there a way to make it faster? How would you write the whole query?
I'm not so good with SQL optimization :-)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have indexes on the fields that you're joining on?

Comment: INDEXES: PROD_sell (PROD_SELL_id), PROD_newsletter (NEWSL_id), PROD_archivio (PROD_ARCH_id), PROD_cat (PROD_CAT_id)

Answer (score 1):

That `OR` condition cannot use an index, so it slows down the query.. The workaround is to split your query into two queries, which are identical except that they each have a different condition from the `OR`. Then combine them using `UNION`.

And of course, make sure you have indexes on all the relevant columns.